# Getting error Error parsing script /server/main.lua:146: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 139) near '='

Tags: lua

Getting error Error parsing script @esx_identity/server/main.lua in resource esx_identity: @esx_identity/server/main.lua:146: '}' expected (to close '{' at line 139) near '='

```
    local lastdigits = math.random(9) .. math.random(9) .. math.random(9) .. math.random(9)
    MySQL.Async.execute('UPDATE `users` SET `firstname` = @firstname, `lastname` = @lastname, `dateofbirth` = @dateofbirth, `sex` = @sex, `height` = @height, `lastdigits` = @lastdigits WHERE identifier = @identifier', {
        ['@identifier']     = identifier,
        ['@firstname']      = data.firstname,
        ['@lastname']       = data.lastname,
        ['@dateofbirth']    = data.dateofbirth,
        ['@sex']            = data.sex,
        ['@height']         = data.height
        ['@lastdigits']     = lastdigits
    }, function(rowsChanged)
        if callback then
            callback(true)
        end
    end)

    MySQL.Async.execute('INSERT INTO characters (identifier, firstname, lastname, dateofbirth, sex, height) VALUES (@identifier, @firstname, @lastname, @dateofbirth, @sex, @height)', {
        ['@identifier']     = identifier,
        ['@firstname']      = data.firstname,
        ['@lastname']       = data.lastname,
        ['@dateofbirth']    = data.dateofbirth,
        ['@sex']            = data.sex,
        ['@height']         = data.height
    })
end
```

Comment: Which line is 146?

Comment: You forgot a comma on the line `['@height']         = data.height` right before the line `['@lastdigits']     = lastdigits`